# javascript regexp, can't get + expression to work

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to pull the number from a string per the CSS format as follows:

```
str == "50.1px"

sz = str.match(/+([0-9]|\.)/)
```

It complains about the `+` expression unless I escape it, but then then `sz` is null.  If I remove the `+` it returns only the first digit.  I'm completely stumped.

Comment: Are you using + to check for 2 or more of some character? It should go after the character class you want to check for multiples of, not before. In this case it looks like you'd want it outside of the parentheses.

Comment: The only reason its not working is this is a wrong regular expression for what you want to do... :)

Answer (score 5):

You should just use Javascripts `.parseFloat()` for that. It will automatically strip away trailing characters.

```
sz = parseFloat('50.1px');  // 50.1
```

MDN:

> parseFloat parses its argument, a string, and returns a floating point
>   number. If it encounters a character other than a sign (+ or -),
>   numeral (0-9), a decimal point, or an exponent, it returns the value
>   up to that point and ignores that character and all succeeding
>   characters. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

Comment: Just as expected from a 49k guy, +1!

Comment: thx for the tip, I will be using that.  I'd still like to know why the way I was using regexp wasn't working though...

Answer (score 1):

You must put the `+` at the end of an expression, such as:

`([0-9])+`

So you can use:

`sz = str.match(/([0-9.])+/)[0]`

Comment: Hi, tested it at [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) and not working: `alert("50.1px".match(/([0-9]|.)+/));` ,neither `alert("50.1px".match(/([0-9]+.?[0-9]+)/));` Do you know how to fix it, please?

Comment: @Stano Try this: `"50.1px".match(/([0-9.])+/)[0]`

Comment: No, I didn't downvote. Only took upvote back, then I gave the upvote back. I almost never downvote.

Comment: `alert("50.1px".match(/([0-9]+\.?[0-9]+)/g));` works just fine. You should replace `.` by `\.`, otherwise it will match even **50f12px**! One strange thing, if I remove the `/g` modifier, I am getting an alert displaying `50.1` twice. Care to explain, anyone?

Comment: @Stano But that's practically the same :) Just kidding :)

Comment: @Cupidvogel I guess it outputs the array, nullth is full matched string, and 1st is the string matched in ()brackets. This can do it: `alert("50.1px".match(/(?:[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+)/));` but I guess it's not very correct. Recently I read about it here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php But I'd like also some simple and true explanation on it.    @SnowBlind :) I was sure I will upvote your answer again, and that's it!

Comment: @SnowBlind Thank you, but I am only beginner in RegExp, always beware it, if possible. Have a good time buddies!

Comment: @SnowBlind... Why do you need that `[0]` at the end of your match function?

Comment: @AdityaParab Because `"50.1px".match(/([0-9.])+/)[0]` returns this array:`[50.1, 1]` and we only need the first item.

Comment: @SnowBlind:
Oh! Thanks,
Whats the 1 at 1st index in returned array?

Comment: @AdityaParab You know what? I've no idea! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `parseFloat`

OR

You can use `jQuery`'s `.height()` and `.width()` APIs to get height and width of the selected elements. These functions return you corresponding height width without px suffix.

If you are so fond of using regular expressions, then this is the correct one

```
var pattern = /[0-9.]+/
```